# Disable boto logging without modifying the boto files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, boto, python-logging

I am using the Boto library to talk to AWS. I want to disable logging. (Or redirect to /dev/null or other file). I can't find an obvious way to do this. I tried this, but that doesn't seem to help:

```
import boto
boto.set_file_logger('boto', 'logs/boto.log')
```

This says it is possible, http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=52727&#52727 but as far as I know the documentation doesn't tell how.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could try

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('boto').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

which will suppress all (other than CRITICAL) errors.

Boto uses logging configuration files (e.g. `/etc/boto.cfg`, `~/.boto`) so see if you can configure it to your needs that way.

The `set_file_logger` call simply adds a user-defined file to the logging setup, so you can't use that to turn logging off.

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason I can't get the boto config files to switch off logging. http://code.google.com/p/boto/issues/detail?id=476

Comment: In django setting this is like this: ```LOGGING['loggers'].update({
    'boto': {
        'level': 'CRITICAL',
    }
})```

Comment: Using boto3, I had to `logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.INFO)`

Comment: I used; logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

Comment: As @charneykaye and @Gerard mention above, because `boto3` is actually two distinct modules, `boto3` and `botocore`, you'll need to suppress both with two calls like this : `logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` and `logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL))`

Comment: Here are all boto3 loggers: `boto3`, `botocore`, `nose`.

Comment: @DmitryVerhoturov - not sure why you classify `nose` as a `boto` logger - `nose` is an independent project which just happens to be used for testing of `boto`, right?

Comment: @VinaySajip, mindless copypaste, sorry. Just checked `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys()` with only boto3 imported,  `bcdocs, boto3, botocore, ndg` are root level loggers which are used.

Answer (score 71):

I move the boto3 answer from the comments (namely  charneykaye and gene_wood) to a proper answer:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler()) # Writes to console
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('s3transfer').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

To get all the loggers follow the [response from leobarcellos](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/521#3453303):

```
import logging
loggers_dict = logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict
```

Comment: Most logging i'm seeing from "boto" is really from s3transfer as noted in @Iony's list.  (boto 1.9.28 and s3transfer 0.1.13).  Note that s3transfer doesn't load until boto3 is _used_ (ie doesn't load when boto3 is loaded) so one should import s3transfer before disabling s3transfer loggers

Comment: Working on an app and botocore killed the logging I was looking to remove.

Comment: I don't understand why this works. If the level is DEBUG and all the boto3 logs are CRITICAL, why these are not appearing in the logs anymore?

Comment: DEBUG is the default and the boto3 log level is changed in the way that only errors critical and higher are presented, as the default boto3 messages are lower - I assume info or debug - they are no longer shown. Did that help?

Answer (score 18):

This is the only solution, which works for me as of today (2020/01/31):

```
for name in ['boto', 'urllib3', 's3transfer', 'boto3', 'botocore', 'nose']:
    logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

The solution with

```
boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.CRITICAL)
```

was killing my whole non-boto logs.
It manipulates the root logger of the standard logging from python.

Try it out for yourself:

```
import logging
import boto3
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.CRITICAL)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.list_buckets()
    logger.info(f'bucket list: {response}')
```

Regardless of where the init of the `logger` happens, it won't bring up the output.
Remove the line of the `boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.CRITICAL)` and the non-boto3 logs will re-appear again!
Consequently the only working solution is **NOT** to use the approach with `boto3.set_stream_logger()` and apply it as I suggested.

Answer (score 11):

Better yet, disable `propagate` for boto:

```
import boto
boto.set_file_logger('boto', 'logs/boto.log')
logging.getLogger('boto').propagate = False
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a new-ish feature, but this should be the accepted answer nowadays.

Comment: I had to use `logging.getLogger("botocore").propagate = False`.

Comment: Why is this "better"?

Comment: If I recall correctly (and I wrote this 5+ years ago), by setting propagate to `False` it prevents it from being handled by other loggers. The second line in my example says "for the 'boto' logger, direct messages to `logs/boto.log`" and the third line says "...and then stop, don't pass it on to any other log handler"

Answer (score 7):

This answer is for those who're using [`logging.config.dictConfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825).

It is recommended to disable DEBUG and INFO messages from all external packages, not limited to `botocore` and `boto3`:

```py
LOGGING_CONFIG = { # Add your preexisting logging config here.
    "loggers": { # Add your preexisting loggers here.
        "": {"level": "WARNING", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},  # Root logger.
     }
```

Alternatively, to disable debug messages from `botocore` and `boto3` but not from all external packages:

```py
LOGGING_CONFIG = { # Add your preexisting config here too.
    "loggers": { # Add your preexisting loggers here too.
        "botocore": {"level": "WARNING", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},
        "boto3": {"level": "WARNING", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},
     }
```

Assuming your logging configuration dict is named `LOGGING`, run this next:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

The above must be **run before boto3 is imported**, irrespective of whether it is imported directly or indirectly! It won't entirely work if it's run after boto3 is already imported. You can choose to replace `"WARNING"` above with `"INFO"` or `"ERROR"` or `"CRITICAL"`.

Comment: Probably the cleanest option, considering the logging config will just work for all packages relying on the logging module.

Answer (score 2):

Beware this solution will disable also non-boto logs.
See [mchlfchr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008283/1410503) instead.

---

For me none of the posted solutions worked unfortunately. Probably due to meanwhile changes in boto itself.

[But sometimes a look into the manual does help..](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.set_stream_logger)

```
import logging
import boto3
boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: if you are using that, then all the other relevant logs (!= boto*) are disappearing as well

Comment: why do they disappear?

Comment: see my extended answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008283/1654284

Comment: I still don't understand why python's root logger is touched by that. But your example shows. Good job, man :) upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There is another annoying property of the logging module in python: if you import logging again (for instance because you import a function from a file where logging is imported) AFTER setting the loglevels for your code, setting the levels might not have any effect. I don't know the exact details of why that is, but I only managed to set correct log levels for imported libraries after implementing something like below, and ALWAYS using a logger created by that function. The file where this logger creation function is defined, is the only file in my code base where logging is imported.

```py
import logging

def get_logger_by_name(logger_name: str, log_filepath: str = "/training.log") -> logging.Logger:
    """
    Function that reloads logging module to store logs into a file and creates logger
    :param logger_name: Name of the logger that is returned
    :param log_filepath: filepath to log_file to store all logs
    :return: logger object
    """
    reload(
        logging
    )  # we need to import logging again to configure log file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553516/11758585
    logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.DEBUG,
            format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-10s %(message)s",
            datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            handlers=[logging.FileHandler(log_filepath), logging.StreamHandler()],
        )
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # clean messy log output by setting log level to WARNING for unimportant loggers
    logging.getLogger("botocore").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("boto3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("boto").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("s3transfer").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    return logger
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with boto3, it can be done by setting a general logging level in **basicConfig**. In the example below we try to check the existence of a file in a bucket on S3 service:

```py
import boto3
import botocore
import logging

logging.basicConfig(..., level=logging.INFO) # ***** HERE IS THE SOLUTION *****

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', ...) # credetials
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

logging.info('INFO TEST')
logging.error('ERROR TEST')
logging.warning('WARNING TEST')

try:
    my_bucket.Object('test/test.txt').load() # it will send some https requests and DEBUG them in logging
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print('The object does not exist.')
else:
    print('The object does exist.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to disable boto and/or other loggers because logs generated by your code are bloated with debug logs of other modules, you can avoid using root logger.

Instead of importing with `logging.getLogger()`, import with `logging.getLogger('module_name')`.

Referred from [a comment](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/521#issuecomment-473504839) to an issue on official boto3 github repo.