# Suppress post output messages

Tags: python, boto

Is there a way to suppress 'POST' messages to console when Boto makes a connection to do things like get_all_instances or connect_to_region, etc. ? e.g.

```
myReservations = myConnection.get_all_instances(filters={'tag-key' : tagKey})
```

This kicks out a big POST message:

> send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:
>   ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding:
>   identity\r\nContent-Length: 264\r\nContent-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nUser-Agent:
>   Boto/2.0
>   (linux2)\r\n\r\nAWSAccessKeyId=ACCESS_KEY_VALUE&Action=DescribeInstances&Filter.1.Name=tag-key&Filter.1.Value.1=stage&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2013-01-03T23%3A46%3A40Z&Version=2011-01-01&Signature=BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH

I don't want to see this message. Nor the reply, nor the header messages.

Comment: What does your boto.cfg file look like? Did you read the documentation, so you know why I'm asking and can immediately tell me that's not it, or did you just copy someone else's configuration without even looking at it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661275/disable-boto-logging-without-modifying-the-boto-files.  More current versions of boto do not log DEBUG messages to the console by default.  There must have been a bug in the particular version you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to boto, but as soon as you said it I realized I set the debug option. Thanks.