# Python Boto Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, boto

I am experimenting with Amazon Web Services Python Boto.  I have built some basic tooling to help me use some features of Amazon Glacier.

I have established some basic logging like so:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='testtest.log',
                level=logging.INFO,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
```

When I put this thing into debug mode it fills up my log file with gibberish of the binary transmission I guess.  All I want from debug is to see the headers and how it's splitting up my multipart upload.  Any ideas how I can tone down debug mode?

Thanks,

Comment: could this help maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661275/disable-boto-logging-without-modifying-the-boto-files