# python logging file is not working when using logging.basicConfig

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have the following lines of code that initialize logging.
I comment one out and leave the other to be used.
The problem that I'm facing is that the one that is meant to log to the file not logging to file. It is instead logging to the console.
Please help.

### For logging to Console:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)
```

### for file logging

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='server-soap.1.log',level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')
```

Comment: your file logging example works fine for me. is the file writable? do you call your config and log calls in the right order?

Comment: Thanks Gryphius. Yes, the definition was ok. But I found that the problem was regarding the ordering of my imports and logging. I needed to define the logging before importing the various libraries.

Answer (score 127):

I found out what the problem was.
It was in the ordering of the imports and the logging definition.

The effect of the poor ordering was that the libraries that I imported before defining the logging using `logging.basicConfig()` defined the logging. This therefore took precedence to the logging that I was trying to define later using `logging.basicConfig()`

Below is how I needed to order it:

```
import logging
## for file logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='server-soap.1.log',
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(threadName)-10s %(message)s',)

from pysimplesoap.server import SoapDispatcher, SOAPHandler
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
import time,random,datetime,pytz,sys,threading
from datetime import timedelta
#DB
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

#ESB Call
from suds import WebFault
from suds.client import Client
```

But the faulty ordering that I initially had was:

```
from pysimplesoap.server import SoapDispatcher, SOAPHandler
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
import logging
import time,random,datetime,pytz,sys,threading
from datetime import timedelta
#DB
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

#ESB Call
from suds import WebFault
from suds.client import Client

## for file logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='server-soap.1.log',
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(threadName)-10s %(message)s',)
```

Comment: Tricky one. This drove me crazy!

Comment: OMG! dude I needed this. I've spent days trying to solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Drove me crazy too. I find some comment of logging.basicConfig, it says:This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
    configured. It is a convenience method intended for use by simple scripts
    to do one-shot configuration of the logging package.

Comment: why is this the case tho.

Comment: @Phil I put a minus because the ordering of imports is not a problem here. The problem is that `basicConfig` should be called in your program not in libraries

Comment: Sorry to just comment the same thing, but OMG this drove me crazy for way too along as well! What made it worse was that it *only* showed up in Docker?? Outside of Docker the exact same code honoured the `basicConfig()` call??

Comment: This is weird because it breaks PEP guidelines on codes within imports, but is the only solution i guess. Maybe there could be a warning message "basicConfig already called" or something.

Comment: this drove me crazy as well but i guess it kind of makes sense...in my case i just made sure that logging configuration is done in the main python file, and not in any of the sub-modules

Comment: Yes ! The documentation says: 

"As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call (of `logging.basicConfig`) will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops."

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#:~:text=only%20the%20first%20call%20will%20actually%20do%20anything

Answer (score 43):

"Changed in version 3.8: The `force` argument was added." I think it's a better choice for new version.

For older Version(< 3.8):

From the [source code of logging](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1831) I found the flows:

> ```
> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
> ```

```
configured. It is a convenience method intended for use by simple scripts
to do one-shot configuration of the logging package.
```

So, if some module we import called the `basicConfig()` method before us, our call will do nothing.

A solution I found can work is that you can **reload logging before your own calling to `basicConfig()`**, such as

```
def init_logger(*, fn=None):

    # !!! here
    from imp import reload # python 2.x don't need to import reload, use it directly
    reload(logging)

    logging_params = {
        'level': logging.INFO,
        'format': '%(asctime)s__[%(levelname)s, %(module)s.%(funcName)s](%(name)s)__[L%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
    }

    if fn is not None:
        logging_params['filename'] = fn

    logging.basicConfig(**logging_params)
    logging.error('init basic configure of logging success')
```

Comment: Notice: You should reload this logging module before import others.

Comment: This force argument was needed in my case. Found it in doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

Answer (score 17):

In case `basicConfig()` does not work:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('Spam Logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug Spam message')
logging.debug('debug Spam message')
logger.info('info Ham message')
logger.warning('warn Eggs message')
logger.error('error Spam and Ham message')
logger.critical('critical Ham and Eggs message')
```

which gives me the following output:

```
2019-06-20 11:33:48,967 - Spam Logger - DEBUG - debug Spam message
2019-06-20 11:33:48,968 - Spam Logger - INFO - info Ham message
2019-06-20 11:33:48,968 - Spam Logger - WARNING - warn Eggs message
2019-06-20 11:33:48,968 - Spam Logger - ERROR - error Spam and Ham message
2019-06-20 11:33:48,968 - Spam Logger - CRITICAL - critical Ham and Eggs message
```

For the sake of reference, [Python Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) is readworthy.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that the `logger.setLevel()` is crucial, because this cost me an hour as I did not notice in the answer; ie even if your handlers have `DEBUG` level, the default for `logger` is `WARN` so your `INFO` and `DEBUG` won't come through without the `logger.setLevel()`.

Comment: Seems least "hackish" from provided answers.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error, I fixed it by passing the following argument to the basic config.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level="WARNING",
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - [ %(message)s ]",
    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
    force=True,
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ])
```

Here as you can see passing `force=True` overrides any other [BasicConfigs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: "Changed in version 3.8: The force argument was added." I think it's a better choice for new version

Comment: Finally, after much head-scratching, this worked! I was looking for a quicker/simpler solution than having to instantiate with `logger = logging.getLogger('abc')`.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.  Thanks so much, adding `force=True` did the trick.

Comment: If you say force =True, how does this change affect other libraries that use the logging module?

Comment: @PythonMaester I think it will force the libraries to use the logging config created by us

Comment: @AlenPaulVarghese this means whatever those libraries will be logging will end up in my debug.log file. This process does not sit well with me

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked for me is instead of tracing down which module might be importing `logging` or even calling `basicConfig` before me is to just call `setLevel` after `basicConfig` again.

```
import os
import logging

RUNTIME_DEBUG_LEVEL = os.environ.get('RUNTIME_DEBUG_LEVEL').upper()
LOGGING_KWARGS = {
    'level': getattr(logging, RUNTIME_DEBUG_LEVEL)
}

logging.basicConfig(**LOGGING_KWARGS)
logging.setLevel(getattr(logging, RUNTIME_DEBUG_LEVEL))
```

Sort of crude, seems hacky, fixed my problem, worth a share.

Comment: I don't get it, what's the point of the `basicConfig` call then?

Comment: Calling `basicConfig` sets up other aspects of logging besides effective level. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

Answer (score 0):

### IF YOU JUST WANT TO SET THE LOG LEVEL OF ALL LOGGERS

---

instead of ordering your imports after logging config:

**just set level on the root level:**

```py
# Option 1:
logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Option 2 - make it configurable:
# env variable + default value INFO
logging.root.setLevel(os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [vacing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553516/2111778) answer mentioned, `basicConfig` has no effect if the root logger already has handlers configured.

I was using `pytest` which seems to set handlers which means the default `logging` setup with loglevel WARNING is active -- so it appears my app fails to log, but **this only happens when executing unit tests with `pytest`**. In a normal app run logs are produced as expected which is enough for my use case.