# python dictionary config doesn't produce logs

Tags: python, python-logging

Il have the following log config:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]

loggers:
  a.b:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
```

I load the config with the following code:

```
import logging.config
import yaml


with open(log_conf_file) as f:

   print(f"log config: {log_conf_file}")
   config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
   logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Then, in a few package I have code such as :

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug(...)
logger.info(...)
```

Despite the fact that I know the logging.config.dictConfig(config) is getting called, and despite that the log level is DEBUG, I am not seeing any logging happening at all when I run the code in fhe forground...

Why ?

Comment: Are you sure that the logging configuration happens before you try to log something?

Comment: And you're sure the `__name__` value is listed in the config?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging file is not working when using logging.basicConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240464/python-logging-file-is-not-working-when-using-logging-basicconfig)