# Python root logger handlers do not get named loggers records?

Tags: python, logging

I have the following setup:

- root logger to log everywhere
- my programm adds a new handler after startup via an callback (for example a database) with `CallbackHandler`
- named logger in my modules do not call into the root-logger

[Online Python Compiler](https://www.online-python.com/tI0vGAqC9d) <sub><- you need to have *main.py* selected to Run *main.py* in there</sub>

*main.py*

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import MyLogger
from MyApp import MyApp

MyLogger.init()

_logger = logging.getLogger() # root

def main() :
    _logger.error( "main - root logger" )
    app = MyApp() # setup app and attach CallbackHandler to root logger
    app.testLog() # call named logger - should call root logger & callback handler

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

*MyLogger.py*

```py
import logging
from logging import LogRecord
import logging.config
import os
from typing import Callable


LOG_PATH = "./logs"

LOGGING_CONFIG : dict = {
    "version" : 1 ,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(name)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    "handlers" : {
        "ConsoleHandler" : {
            "class" : "logging.StreamHandler" ,
            "formatter" : "simple" ,
        } ,
    } ,
    "root" : {
        "handlers" : [
            "ConsoleHandler" ,
            ] ,
        "level" : "DEBUG" ,
    }
}

def init() :
    os.makedirs( LOG_PATH , exist_ok = True )
    logging.config.dictConfig( LOGGING_CONFIG )


class CallbackHandler( logging.Handler ) :
    def __init__( self , level = logging.DEBUG , callback : Callable = None ) :
        super().__init__( level )
        self._callback = callback

    def emit( self , record : LogRecord ) :
        if self._callback is not None :
            self._callback( record.name + " | " + record.msg )
```

*MyApp.py*

```py
import logging
from MyLogger import CallbackHandler


_logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )


class MyApp :
    def __init__( self ) :
        rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
        rootLogger.addHandler( CallbackHandler( callback = self.myCallback ) )

    def myCallback( self , msg : str ) :
        print( "CALLBACK: " + msg )

    def testLog( self ) :
        _logger.error( "MyApp.testLog() - named logger" )
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) say, named loggers do not inherit the parents handlers.
But they propagate their log messages to the parent/root logger - which has handlers attached.
However they do not get called with a named logger.

The Problem: **`CallbackHandler.emit()` is not called**

(if I remove the `__name__` in `MyApp.py: logging.getLogger()`, the root logger gets referenced and the Callback-Handler is called)

How do I :

1. initialize the root logger
2. later in my program attach a custom Handler to the root logger
3. use named loggers in my program
4. propagate the the logs from named loggers to the root logger
5. such that the logs use the custom root-logger-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix: add the following line to your `LOGGING_CONFIG` dict:

```
"disable_existing_loggers" : False,
```

---

The problem is that the child logger is created before the logging gets its configuration and the default behaviour when configuring the logging is to disable existing loggers. [Link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) (it's the last item in that section).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is, to have the name of the module within the log statement.

This is also the recommended way, you initialise the logger with it's configuration in `main.py` file and in rest of the module you use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, the name of the logger automatically becomes the module name and it inherits the configuration of the root logger.

Although, you have to pay attention to module's import order and that's the reason why it wasn't working in your case. More detailed explaination you can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240464/python-logging-file-is-not-working-when-using-logging-basicconfig)

```py
# ./main.py

import logging
import logging.config

from MyLogger import LOGGING_CONFIG

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)

from MyApp import MyApp

_logger = logging.getLogger()  # root


def main():
    _logger.error("main - root logger")
    app = MyApp()  # setup app and attach CallbackHandler to root logger
    app.testLog()  # call named logger - should call root logger & callback handler


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# ./MyLogger.py

LOG_PATH = "./logs"

LOGGING_CONFIG: dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {"format": "%(name)s - %(message)s"},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "ConsoleHandler": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {"handlers": ["ConsoleHandler"], "level": "DEBUG", "propagate": False}
    },
}
```

```py
# ./MyApp.py

import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        _logger.info("from myapp")

    def myCallback(self, msg: str):
        print("CALLBACK: " + msg)

    def testLog(self):
        _logger.info("MyApp.testLog() - named logger")
        _logger.error("MyApp.testLog() - named logger")
```

This setup produces the following output

```
root - main - root logger
MyApp - from myapp
MyApp - MyApp.testLog() - named logger
MyApp - MyApp.testLog() - named logger
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I clarified my question.
I try to add a custom handler _after_ startup of my app, attach it to the root logger, but I want to use named loggers in my program.
However, the named loggers seem to not call into this custom handler (they dont propagate to the root)