# Inconsistent behaviour with Python loggings when creating a package (__init__.py and from . import module)

Tags: python, logging, package

Here is a MRE:

`my_package/__init__.py`

```py
import logging

from . import module, a_second_module

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

`my_package/module.py`

```py
import logging

def module():
    logging.info("Doing something...")
    logging.debug("This is a debug message and won't show up by default.")
```

`my_package/a_second_module.py`

```py
import logging
from my_package_test_so_poetry.module import module

logging.warning("Warning from a_second_module.py")

def module2():
    module()
    print("Doing something else...")
```

The `logging.basicConfig` does not affect the logging behaviour of the second file (`module.py`).
Since when I do (in the terminal)

```py
python (to enter the Python console)
from my_package.module import module
module()
```

I get

```py
WARNING:root:Warning from a_second_module.py
```

But I'm lacking the

```py
INFO:root:Doing something...
```

of the function `module`

I think the problem comes from the warning since the documentation says:

> Log a message with severity 'WARNING' on the root logger. If the
> logger has no handlers, call basicConfig() to add a console handler
> with a pre-defined format.

But I'm not sure I understand why, my `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` (in the `__init__.py` file) should be called *after* the warning message and *before* I call `module`. I'm 99% sure the culprit is the warning message though because everything works as expected without it.

I'm using `PyCharm 2023.3.3 (Professional Edition)` (and I assume other IDEs would have the same behaviour) and `Python 3.11.1`.

Comment: `do_something()` was never called, and `module` isn't generally callable; your examples are very unclear with what you are trying to get at.  Moreover, you should _never_ set up the logging module (e.g. use `logging.basicConfig`) outside of application entry points, so modules in general should never call that as that may result in unexpected behaviors by downstream users of that module.

Comment: that was a typo sorry, the function name was module in my files - I've updated the MRE and you should be able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: What do you mean by "application entry points"? Sorry I'm not familiar with the term and a beginner in programmation

Comment: Typically it's the main function (or script) that is called when a program is started, so if a script is run directly (e.g. `python script.py`) the `script.py` function as the entry point. In Python this is guarded by the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163) block.  Moreover, you actually have set up the logger via `logging.basicConfig` **after** it already ran a `logging.info` onto the root logger (via the import of `a_second_module`), which triggers default configuration as you've identified.  This is why the need to set the logger up at the entry point.

Comment: Basically, either drop the import of `a_second_module`, or set up `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` before any logging is done, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240464/python-logging-file-is-not-working-when-using-logging-basicconfig).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I'm failing to understand is that I'm calling `module()` after setting up the logger via `logging.basicConfig` and no calls to `logging.info` or `logging.warning` are done in between. Why would this not work?

Comment: Because `from . import module, a_second_module` came before `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`, and `a_second_module.py` called `logging.warning("Warning from a_second_module.py")`, which sets up the default logger which ignores info messages. Subsequent calls to `basicConfig` will have no effect, as documented.

Comment: I see, or I could use the optional keyword argument `force`? "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument force is set to True."