# How to stop logger logging logs from other modules?

Tags: python, logging

I havea logger.py file where i have declared my logger

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(filename)s : %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

And in my file store_to_s3.py

```
try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key, aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key)
    logger.info('Successfully connected to AWS services')
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Connection to AWS services failed')


for file in os.listdir(DATA_DIR):
    if '.csv' in file:        
        try:
            s3.upload_file(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, file), credentials.bucket_name, str(file))
            logger.info('Successfully uploaded ' + file +' file to ' + credentials.bucket_name + ' S3 bucket')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Uploading ' + file +' file to ' + credentials.bucket_name + ' S3 bucket failed')
```

And instead of getting logs only from the ones specified  in here i get logs from other modules as well that get called during the execution of the code. The list is long but this is a part of it. How can i avoid this from happening?

```
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] loaders.py : Loading JSON file: C:\Users\serda\Desktop\assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\endpoints.json
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] loaders.py : Loading JSON file: C:\Users\serda\Desktop\assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\sdk-default-configuration.json
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x000001D876834A60>
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] loaders.py : Loading JSON file: C:\Users\serda\Desktop\assignment\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\s3\2006-03-01\service-2.json
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x000001D8767AE170>
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function lazy_call.<locals>._handler at 0x000001D873CB3E20>
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] hooks.py : Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x000001D8767ADF30>
    01-06-2022 11:34:35 [DEBUG] endpoint.py : Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
```

Comment: this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814387/641892